# « J'habite —/dans/sur (la) rue X » : fréquence d'emploi, généralisations ?

Tags: prépositions, régionalismes, indications-de-lieu, toponymes, fréquence-utilisation

> J'habite rue Mont-Royal.
>  J'habite *dans* la rue Mont-Royal.
> J'habite *sur* la rue Mont-Royal.

Je regarde un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=habite%20sur%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%2Chabite%20dans%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%2Chabite%20rue%20_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=8&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chabite%20sur%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20dans%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chabite%20sur%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20dans%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0) en me demandant si ce que j'y vois est significatif. Je lis qu'un emploi [critiqué](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5333) avec la préposition *sur* serait passé dans l'usage standard ([Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/habiter)) ; assez généralement je lis qu'en Belgique et au Canada, on aime bien employer *sur la rue* pour *dans la rue* dans différents contextes. (LBU14 § 1049)

Sait-on si dans sa région (ou les régions pour lesquelles on décide de répondre) :

- On emploie aujourd'hui *habiter* avec *rue* (suivi du nom de la rue, comme dans les exemples) sans
  préposition près de 25 fois plus (donc vraiment beaucoup plus) qu'une formulation avec une
  préposition ; le tour avec une préposition est-il devenu inusité dans ce cas précis ?
- Quand on formule avec la préposition dans ce cas précis, on choisira 3 fois plus (donc clairement plus) souvent *dans* que *sur* ; trouve-t-on les deux formulations courantes, équivalentes ?

Comment: Voici le lien d'une discussion qui pourrait t'intéresser. [habiter (dans/à/sur) (la) rue/avenue/place X](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/habiter-dans-%C3%A0-sur-la-rue-avenue-place-x-habiter-au-num%C3%A9ro-z-de-la-rue-x-pr%C3%A9position-article.710696/)

Comment: Les Ngrams ne reflètent pas comment les gens parlent. Les Ngrams sont surtout un outil utile pour les textes écrits. Je ne sais pas pourquoi ici on pense que les Ngrams révèlent les secrets de la langue parlée dans différentes régions francophones.

Comment: If faut regarder chaque occurrence dans les Ngrams. Sans quoi, on ne sait pas si c'est parlé ou écrit. En générale, les gens citent Ngrams sans la distinction. Cela ne vaut pas grande chose, à mon avis, pour voir si x se dit ou ne se dit pas. Voilà l'utilité.

Comment: Pour moi c'est "sur" qui est le plus naturel... mais la plupart ne seront pas de même avis.

Comment: @Oreste J'ai jamais su que j'avais même le choix avant hier. Ce sont des nuances régionales, ce qui est le plus naturel c'est souvent ce qu'on a lu ou entendu le plus.

Comment: [Relié](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/47284/26366).

Answer (score 1):

[france](/questions/tagged/france)

Oui, nous utilisons *habiter rue ...* et *habiter dans la rue ...*. Les deux utilisations sont courantes : la première est principalement utilisée à l'oral, contrairement à la deuxième qui est plus utilisée à l'écrit.

Par contre, *habiter sur la rue ...* n'est pas utilisé. Même si personnellement, je comprendrais si on me le disait, je trouverais ça bizarre.

À propos du [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=habite%20sur%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%2Chabite%20dans%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%2Chabite%20rue%20_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=8&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chabite%20sur%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20dans%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chabite%20sur%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20dans%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0), je ne pense pas que cela soit représentatif de la manière de parler/écrire des gens. Par exemple je ne vais pas chercher "*quel est le nombre de gens habitant en France*" mais juste "*population France*". Ainsi, c'est généralement pratique pour savoir si les gens connaissent un mot ou voir s'ils l'utilisent beaucoup, mais pas pour connaître leur manière d'utiliser la langue.

Comment: Habituer et habiter n'est pas la même chose... Et habiter sur la rue semble tout à fait naturel pour moi.

Comment: Effectivement, c'est juste une faute de frappe. Désolé... Tu es d'où ?

Comment: Au vu de cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=habite+rue%2Chabite+dans+la+rue&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chabite%20rue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20dans%20la%20rue%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chabite%20rue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20dans%20la%20rue%3B%2Cc0), il est apparent qu'une modification est nécessaire dans votre réponse.

Comment: 1) "principalement" donc ça ne m'étonne pas qu'il soit utilisé. 2) les recherches google, pour moi, ne correspondent pas à comment je parle ou écris. je vais chercher des mots clés. Par exemple je ne vais pas chercher "*quel est le nombre de gens habitant en France*" mais juste "*population France*". Je vais l'ajouter à ma réponse

Comment: Les recherches Google, _évidemment_, ne correspondent pas à votre façon d'écrire personnelle, mais cette façon particulière n'est ni le concernement des recherches ni celui du FSE. Ces recherches reflètent ce qui est dans les livres. Vous pouvez continuer à vérifier et  trouver, par exemple, que c'est la même chose pour la troisième personne du pluriel: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=habitent+rue%2Chabitent+dans+la+rue&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chabitent%20rue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabitent%20dans%20la%20rue%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Ah, je savais pas. Merci de l'info, c'est je m'y attendais pas

Comment: As-tu l'impression que le tour sans la préposition est vraiment beaucoup plus utilisé ?

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Pour qui a vecu en France, J'habite rue ou avenue [x] s'entend partout.

Comment: Il n'y en a aucun qui est plus utilisé que l'autre. Il n'y a que le moment où on l'utilise qui change

Answer (score 1):

Les deux questions sont intéressantes mais n'ont pas vraiment une réponse claire puisque les réponses vont dépendre des régions. Je pense que l'article que tu as lié explique très bien la situation au Québec. J'étais quand même surpris de voir que l'utilisation sans préposition ou déterminant est aussi fréquente, car au Québec, selon moi, c'est surtout utilisé dans des annoncements (ex: "Il y a des travaux boulevard [...]"). Ce genre d'utilisation est plus rare à l'oral ou pour *habiter*.

Une autre possibilité serait "habiter la rue". Je l'ai ajouté à ta [recherche](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=habite%20sur%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%2Chabite%20dans%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%2Chabite%20rue%20_NOUN_%2Chabite%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=8&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chabite%20sur%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20dans%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabite%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0) et il est effectivement plus utilisé que les deux autres. **Toutes ces utilisations sont logiques d'une certaine manière** et change le point de vue. Plus précisément, on change la définition de *rue*. Avec "la", on énonce simplement un *endroit* où l'on demeure, avec "sur", on ajoute l'information que notre demeure est sur une *surface* et finalement, et avec "dans", on voit plutôt la rue comme un *volume* incluant verticalement l'espace au dessus.

Si quelqu'un critique l'utilisation de "sur", il critique aussi d'une certaine manière "dans" puisqu'on décrit une relation spatiale. Une critique de "sur" s'écroule rapidement si on veut débattre de sa logique.

Personnellement, je préfère et utilise "habiter sur la rue" et c'est probablement parce que je suis Québécois et qu'au Québec, l'usage est plus répandue (qu'en France). On voit la formulation apparaître dans la culture, un exemple qui me vient notamment en tête est la chanson des Colocs "[La rue principale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2o4HSzd-wY&ab_channel=savoie31)" (1995). On y voit apparaître l'expression "su'a rue principale".

Comment: Ce sur me parait venir de l'anglais. Non? Qu'on le dise, c'est très bien. En France on le dirait pas.

Comment: @Lambie C'est possible, mais qu'il vienne de l'anglais ou non, au final il n'y a rien d'illogique et c'est pourquoi on l'utilise au Québec. Est-ce que ça montre une différence d'ouverture? Qui sait... Je suis sûr que certains critiquerait sont utilisation même au Québec, mais la motivation vient plus d'une peur du changement en général selon moi.

Comment: Je ne sais pas. Il me semble que les gens **parlent comme ils parlent**. Par contre, un truc peut devenir logique dans une région et pas dans une autre. Les anglais disent: I saw the man in the road yesterday. Les américains disent: I saw the man on the street yesterday.  In the high street/on main street, aussi.

Comment: @Lambie C'est une preuve que c'est donc logique. Il y a une **différence entre être logique et être utilisé**. Vous semblez utiliser "habiter dans la rue" en France couramment. Pourquoi est-ce que tout d'un coup cette logique s'envole pour les autres choses? Au Québec, "voir quelqu'un dans la rue" est très naturel, en tout cas pour moi.

Comment: Personellement, je n'habite plus en France. Mais je dirais: le marché se trouve dans la rue x, mais **J'habite la Rue de Montreuil. Oui, en français, voir quelqu'un dans la rue. Je donnais l'exemple en anglais pour montrer la différence régionale. en anglais Tout comme vous au Québec, vous dites: sur la rue. mais qu'en France on ne le dirait pas. Vive la différence! :)

Comment: @Lambie Ah je comprends, mais oui en effet chaque régions choisissent celui qu'ils préfèrent mais je ne pense pas personnellement que de limiter la langue sur un point aussi futile est une bonne chose. Je pourrais très bien voir une autre région du monde qui ont choisi d'utiliser "sur la rue" pour tout. Ça sonnerait bizarre au début, mais logiquement il n'y a aucun problème.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+trouve+rue+_NOUN_%2Ctrouve+dans+la+rue_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrouve%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @LPH https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trouve+rue+_NOUN_%2Ctrouve+la+rue+_NOUN_%2Ctrouve+dans+la+rue+_NOUN_%2C+trouve+sur+la+rue+_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrouve%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrouve%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrouve%20dans%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrouve%20sur%20la%20rue%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0 Au Québec on se demanderait pourquoi vous n'utilisez pas de déterminant? Évidemment on n'utilise pas "trouve dans la rue" pour parler de trouver *la* rue. Ta requête n'avait pas fonctionnée.

Comment: @Simon Il n'est pas question de « trouver » mais de « trouve », qui est l'abréviation de « se trouve ». Si rien n'apparait pour « trouve » alors forcément il y en a encore moins pour « se trouve ». En français de France « se trouve rue X » est courant à la fois dans le parler et l'écrit.

Comment: @LPH En effet j'ai oublié de prendre en considération l'autre définition de trouve. Par contre, regarde mon ngram, tu as fais une erreur dans ta requête. Il y a des résultats, mais pas pour "se trouve". Par contre, la raison ici est que, comme j'ai mentionné dans ma réponse, on utilise généralement cette forme pour les annoncements. "Il se trouve rue [...]" en fait partie.

Comment: @Simon Exact. Dans l'ngram corrigé on voit donc que la forme sans préposition est la plus courante dans les textes. Ce n'est pas le cas en France, la forme courte est utilisée dans les dialogues.

Comment: @LPH Je ne connais pas les sources de Google, mais est-ce qu'ils incluent des ouvrages québécois? Ce serait beaucoup plus intéressant si on avait l'option de comparer, mais je peux te garantir que sans préposition ou déterminant ça sonne bizarre au Québec. Vous dites aussi "Je suis présentement rue [...]"? D'un point de vue grammatical, on dirait que ça dit "Je suis en ce moment une rue"...

Comment: @Simon Je suppose que leur corpus est équilibré de façon à bien représenter toutes les variétés ; il serait surprenant que cet organisme ait négligé cet aspect, mais je n'ai aucune certitude ; mais prenons cette locution québécoise, « crisse que », et essayons là ; on voit qu'il doit y avoir un nombre important de livres du québec dans le corpus : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crisse+que+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrisse%20que%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccrisse%20que%3B%2Cc0 //  Je ne doute pas que ce soit différent au québec. // Oui, amusant.

Comment: @Eyla Pour être honnête j'utiliserais "du" dans ce cas, mais bon. C'est pour ça que ma réponse précise que toutes les formulations sont logiques et c'est aussi pour ça que j'ai préciser que la question n'avait pas vraiment de réponse. J'aime la question car c'est une belle discussion, mais je pense que le format de StackExchange veut éviter les dicussions.

Comment: @Eyla aaaah, confusion haha, je suis des alentours de Montréal.

Answer (score 1):

Pour moi, la forme standard et largement la plus courante se passe de préposition, quel que soit le registre, à l'écrit comme à l'oral.

> J'**habite rue** machin.

J'entend parfois la préposition **dans** mais c'est moins naturel à mon oreille :

> J'habite **dans** la rue de Vaugirard.

ou alors, ce n'est pas d'une adresse qu'il s'agit et **dans** s'impose, par exemple :

> J'habite **dans** la rue qui monte vers le château.

Peut-être que ce *dans* sert à insister, comme dans la paire *j'habite Paris* comparé à *J'habite dans Paris*.

En Suisse et en Belgique, j'ai souvent entendu j'habite **à** la rue machin :

> Moi j’habite **à** la rue de Carouge depuis plus de 30ans je suis allée à pizzaland 10 plein de fois. ([tripadvisor, Suisse](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/ShowUserReviews-g664427-d13531005-r684182640-Pizzaland_10-Carouge.html))

> Je m'appelle Yara j'ai 14 ans je suis en 2ème du cycle j'habite **à** la rue de la scierie 5  ([tophelp, forum suisse](https://tophelp.ch/fr/services/garde-animaux/martigny-1920))

Note: En Suisse, on met le numéro de rue après le nom, il se place avant en France et en Belgique.

> Comme vous le savez, j'habite à la Rue de la Courbette à Athis ([Courrier à la commune d'Honnelles, Belgique](https://www.honnelles.be/ma-commune/vie-politique/le-college-communal/espace-conseillers-communaux/college-du-6-aout/mail-devlaeminck.pdf))

Je n'avais en revanche jamais rencontré *j'habite **sur** la rue machin* avant cette question mais la préposition *sur* est en progression dans d'autres cas comme *je vais **sur** Bordeaux* ou *Je cherche un appart **sur** Lyon*. Avec une rue, je pourrais dire :

> *Ma maison donne **sur** la rue de la Paix*.

Quand il s'agit d'une route et pas d'une rue, **sur** remplace **dans** :

> J'habite sur la route de verneuil aux mureaux (à côté de EADS) ([nounou.top](https://www.nounou-top.fr/assistante-maternelle-les-mureaux-78130-81))

Comment: Oui, je ne sais pas trop l'expliquer parce que *j'habite sur la route XXX* me paraît courant. Peut-être une question de relief, la rue est un volume alors que la route est un plan. Tiens, ça me rappelle une fameuse *route plane* ;-)